# Editing shapefile Item Description > Summary in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, metadata

Is there a way to edit a shapefile's Item Description > Summary in ArcPy?

I can right click on the shapefile in catalog, select Item Description, then click edit... but I want to automate this in arcpy. I also want to keep the default metadata format. Screenshot below is example of default metadata format, with my manual edits to Summary (not done in arcpy).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure ArcPy the way to do this is to save a copy of the item's metadata to an XML file, modify it, then save the XML back to the original ArcGIS item.  From the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/metadata/editing-metadata-for-many-arcgis-items.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_35F23B7429E8484890058C3C7A797D6E):

> Another approach is to use a Python script to update an item's
>   metadata content. The Python script must execute the same
>   geoprocessing tools as the model described above that processes
>   metadata using an XSLT stylesheet. The XSLT Transformation tool is
>   used first to save a copy of the item's metadata to an XML file using
>   the exact copy of.xslt stylesheet provided with ArcGIS Desktop. The
>   resulting XML file can be modified with a Python script. Then, the
>   updated XML document must be saved back to the original ArcGIS item as
>   its metadata using the Metadata Importer tool.

There is a 3rd party python library that automates this - [Arcpy Metadata Editor (arcpy_metadata)](https://github.com/ucd-cws/arcpy_metadata)

Note if using ArcGIS Desktop, these metadata tools are only available in  32bit Python (i.e. not the 64bit background geoprocessing python)

Comment: This arcpy_metadata package worked well! I am running ArcMap 10.6, and I converted my .py into a toolbox tool. Works like a charm, many thanks.

Comment: Small note: I had to install pip first, and then intall the arcpy_metadata package from command prompt to get it to run in my ArcMap tool. Initally, I was able to easily install the arcpy_metadata package in PyCharm and get it to run, but apparently the directory to which it was installed was not mapped by Arc(?).

In case anyone has the same question, I followed the pip install instructions here (half way down the page): https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation